New images not recognized by nextjs
In my Nextjs project, I have some images in public/images. ALl the images that I added a week ago, can be displayed by next/image without problem:
<Image
        src={`/images/${img}.jpg`}
        alt="Beschreibung des Bildes"
        width={300} 
        height={300}
        className="sight__img"
        />

But yesterday I added new images that I want to display in another component. But somehow nexjs does not recognize them.
<Image 
     src="/images/fr.png"
     alt={`${loc} flag`} 
     width={300} 
     height={300} 
                      />

Before you ask: Yes, the new images like fr.png are in my public/images directory. But nextjs does not recognize them. It just says, that they do not exist, although they obviously exist under the correct path.
I am getting:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
But when I display the old pictures again in this component, it can be recognized. But all images, I added yesterday are not recognized.
I already started the server again multiple times, deleted my browser cache, deleted .next folder, but the newly added images are never recognized by nextjs.
